# Write date to cell and change date format

Tags: excel, vba

I have some issue with my VBA code. I got Date variable that stored as `dd/mm/yyyy` but when I write the date to a specific cell the format change to `mm/dd/yyyy`, I have been trying many options but none of them worked for me, I also check that the variable know what is the current day, month and year.

The code:

```
Sheets("report_orders").Select
Range("A1").Value = customerName
Range("A2").Value = "äæîðä " & orderID
Range("A3").Value = "äæîðä ì÷åç " & orderPo
'Range("B2").Value = orderDate
Range("B2").Value = Day(orderDate) & "/" & Month(orderDate) & "/" & Year(orderDate)
Debug.Print "year " & Year(orderDate)
Debug.Print "month " & Month(orderDate)
Debug.Print "day " & Day(orderDate)
```

[image: date value]

but the result is :

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat

Comment: You can use `Format()` function.

Comment: `Date variable that stored as dd/mm/yyyy` - it isn't stored that way because `Date` variables do not have a format. You should remove your code and replace it with `Range("B2").Value = orderDate`, and you should apply the date formatting that you want to the cell.

Comment: I try this all, no one of those options worked

Comment: Just saw the link @braX. Deleted my answer. Please post it as an answer :)

Comment: @lidorag did you try what was BraX suggested? `Range("B2").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"` and then `Range("B2").Value = orderDate`. It iwll definitely work

Comment: Siddharth Rout, it actually worked write the cell format before placing the date in it
thank you all, its works well now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put a date into a cell, you can format it using `.NumberFormat`. Ensure that you format the cell **before** entering the value. For example

```
Range("B2").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
Range("B2").Value = orderDate
```

You can read more about the `.NumberFormat` in [Range.NumberFormat property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat)

Comment: I made a some changes. Feel free to rollback if you do not like the changes :)

Comment: @Gustav. That is not the right edit. I have rolled it back. Please ensure you understand before you edit an answer :) The cell has to be formatted first before you enter the date. This is also confirmed by OP in the comment below the quesiton ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I didn't roll it back, I corrected it because your statement is wrong. The numberformat can be applied at any time. But I misread the request for the date format, sorry.

Comment: `@SiddharthRout: I didn't roll it back, I corrected it because your statement is wrong. The numberformat can be applied at any time. But I misread the request for the date format, sorry. – Gustav just now` @Gustav: I never said you rolled it back :) Also my statement is not wrong. Regarding. .. `The numberformat can be applied at any time.` I never disputed this fact. you can apply it anytime. But to see the effect, you have to apply it **before** you enter the date.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: _I never disputed this fact. you can apply it anytime. But to see the effect, you have to apply it before you enter the date._ ... So you can, but you can't. Confused? You can, of course, modify the format whenever you wish, and the display will change accordingly.

Comment: `@SiddharthRout: I never disputed this fact. you can apply it anytime. But to see the effect, you have to apply it before you enter the date. ... So you can, but you can't. Confused? You can, of course, modify the format whenever you wish, and the display will change accordingly. – Gustav just now` @Gustav: You are mistaken. It will not change if you apply the formatting later (Unless you press `F2-Enter`). *As also confirmed by OP* - See his last comment under the quesiton.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Your statement is not correct, and you should be able easily to check it out: _set value, watch default output, set numberformat, watch the output, confirm format, set another numberformat, watch output, confirm changed format._ No F2, no refresh, no nothing.

Comment: @Gustav: I rest my case :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: OK, if you deny facts, so be it. EOD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227797/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-gustav). @Gustav